# Problem with simulation STP Temperature Measurement Ideal Gas Program in Tobochnik

Tags: statistical-mechanics

The simulation I am considering is provided [here](http://www.compadre.org/STP/items/detail.cfm?ID=7264).
(In case the link no longer works, the program is called 'STP Temperature Measurement Ideal Gas Program' and the homepage of the website is [here](http://www.compadre.org/STP/).  Note: STP stands for "Statistical and Thermal Physics" which is the textbook by H. Gould and J. Tobochnik.)

It is supposed to illustrate how the Demon is an ideal thermometer.

When I run the program and vary all parameters (the number of particles N, the total energy E, or the number of dimensions D), it appears there is **no change** in the average energy $\langle E_d\rangle$ of the demon or the average energy $\langle E\rangle$ of the system.

It always reads $\langle E_d\rangle \approx .66$ and $\langle E\rangle \approx 40$.  How can this be?  Is there a malfunction with the program based on what should happen (I don't know what should happen)?

Comment: You might want to include a small summary (perhaps only key-points) of the link in your question itself. Links can go dead, making the question impossible to understand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about troubleshooting software, not physics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind:  If that is the case, then it is an inefficiency of this website.  Clearly, my goal is to learn physics and this question is intended to help me achieve that goal.

Comment: Can you formulate your question independently of the function of a program? What you perceive as an inefficiency is a well chosen site rule. It allows us to focus on what we do best. Debugging code is simply not it.

Comment: Of course I cannot.  I understand why the rule exists.  In this particular situation it seems a shame that someone in the future may have the same problem and won't be able to find this excellent answer.  Is it worth deleting the question in order to maintain strict adherence to this rule?  I guess that's the community's call.  I don't necessarily see the positive outweighing the negative here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read in the documentation that came with this simulator that when you change the number of particles "N", the total energy of the system "E" or the number of dimensions, the field will turn yellow (which indicates that the simulator has not incorporated the changes) until you hit enter.

I made changes to these values, hit enter with the cursor *still in the field*, and the yellow went away and the simulator performed differently, along with different results in the top for total system energy, etc.